# Progress bar & Loading text not showing up everything looks correct in my code

Tags: android, android-webview, android-progressbar

I'm using local html files which contains links in it but when i click on links it is not showing up progress bar & loading text in webview
this is my Mainactivity.java file

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

```
WebView wv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_exit) {
        System.exit(0);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    TextView txt =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtload);
    ProgressBar pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pg1);

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/error.html");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        System.out.println("loading... please wait");

        pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        System.out.println("finished loading");

        pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
}
```

**content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtload"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Loading... Please Wait"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="209dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pg1"
        style="@android:style/Animation.Dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="4dp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"></WebView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android studio displays the views in the order that they appear in the XML file. What you need to do is reorder the views. The webview should be first then followed by the Textview and then the progress view. 
Thing is, it's in the app and it's showing, just not to the user or to you while running the app. The webview is obscuring the others. See if it will help and mark as correct answer.